# Run a query on a remote database with cordova?

Tags: php, angularjs, cordova

I started working on Cordova recently (starter), I have built my API and let it handle the request based on the request type in the URL.
For example: I have a table called User, so I am expecting to send a request that has the following URL

> [www.mydomain.something?myRequest=RegisterUser](http://www.mydomain.something?myRequest=RegisterUser)

In my API I will get the myRequest and pass it to a function called RegisterUser($arr). This array holds the user credentials.

My question is how to send that request from the client side (AngularJS/Cordova), and is there a way to protect the data that the server side (PHP) will return as a JSON array? For example, if somebody knows the domain and one of my API function names, (s)he can proceed a request such as

> [www.mydomain.something?requestType=getAllUsers](http://www.mydomain.something?requestType=getAllUsers)

this request will bring all the users from the database!! and anyone can see the returned JSON array using POSTMAN

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An access token maybe?

Comment: Use some kind of authentication. Access token, API key, or username encrypted ...

Comment: The thing is, how can I add this access token to my API. I understood that I need to generate a code.. but then what do I have to do and should I pass it with the URL?

Comment: don't use the ? query string, try to call your Api using ajax post call with Cors enabled and json data type, then in your data, you can have Server side encrypted user name and password